# Pandas series mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
data = [
{'A': [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], 'B':[27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0], 'C': ['lic1'],
 'D': ['soy1'], 'E': ['foo1']},
{'A': [7.0, 11.0, 90.0, 43.0, 87.0], 'B':[27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0], 'C': ['lic1'],
 'D': ['soy1'], 'E': ['foo1']},
# ... etc
```

]

The data on 'A' is a Pandas Series.  I would like to compute the average and standard deviation for the data in 'A' (there are several records for A) for example:  (mean=(2.0+3.0+4.0+5.0+6.0+7.0+11.0+90.0+43.0+87.0)/len(A)=25.8)

Comment: all_as = reduce( (lambda x, y: x['A'] + y['A']), data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then `mean` or `std`.

For converting to `float` (`int`) add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), if still problem need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'`.

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(x['A']) for x in data]).astype(float)
print (s)
0     2.0
1     3.0
2     4.0
3     5.0
4     6.0
0     7.0
1    11.0
2    90.0
3    43.0
4    87.0
dtype: float64

print (s.mean())
25.8

print (s.std())
35.15299892375234
```

Another solution:

```
from  itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable([x['A'] for x in data]))).astype(float)
print (s)
0     2.0
1     3.0
2     4.0
3     5.0
4     6.0
5     7.0
6    11.0
7    90.0
8    43.0
9    87.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The data on 'A' are strings.  [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0].  How can i convert them to floats so that I can use the .mean()?

Comment: I've tried both solutions but both of them give me this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: what return `[x['A'] for x in data]` ?

Comment: `[[3181    2.0
  3193    3.0
  3205    4.0
  3217    5.0
  3229    6.0
  Name: A, dtype: float64],
[8016    7.0
  8028    11.0
  8040    90.0
  8052    43.0
  8064    87.0
  Name: A, dtype: float64]]`

Comment: and if `a = [x['A'] for x in data]` then `type(a[0])` ?

Comment: it outputs 'list'

Comment: It seem I get it. Try `s = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable([x['A'].values.tolist() for x in data]))).astype(float)`