# How to calculate the standard deviation and mean of each series in a list

Tags: python, list, pandas

[image]

How to  calculate the standard deviation and mean of each series in a list shown above.

Comment: Please submit question material as text, not screenshots, and show what you have done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas series mean and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933372/pandas-series-mean-and-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has built in `mean` and `std` methods for Series:

```
[(x.mean(), x.std()) for x in data]
```

Output:

```
[(0.49934333895737004, 0.27461607837320307),
 (0.48249584271287005, 0.29392453866333784),
 (0.5253031047833215, 0.2915732660895214),
 (0.502227202304306, 0.2800155771737585),
 (0.45248717136739863, 0.3065349918155113),
 (0.524076962361421, 0.30774118943725953),
 (0.49854839726526873, 0.2903590219165625)]
```

Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

np.random.seed(123)
data = [pd.Series(x) for x in np.random.random(size=(7,245))]
```